# Can I launch Tomboy Notes over ssh

Tags: command-line, ssh, tomboy

I have a few machines running Ubuntu and often I need to run an application from one machine on another. So I use ssh to do this as I already have it set up and it is simple to do.

For example

```
ssh -X netbook liferea
```

This works well for me as I don't have to sync files or install applications on all my machines.

When I try to do this with Tomboy Notes I get errors:

```
ssh -X netbook tomboy

Unhandled Exception: System.Exception: Unable to open the session message bus. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: address
  at NDesk.DBus.Bus.Open (System.String address) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NDesk.DBus.Bus.get_Session () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at NDesk.DBus.Bus.get_Session () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NDesk.DBus.BusG.Init () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Tomboy.GnomeApplication.Initialize (System.String locale_dir, System.String display_name, System.String process_name, System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Tomboy.Application.Initialize (System.String locale_dir, System.String display_name, System.String process_name, System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Tomboy.Tomboy.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Is it possible to launch Tomboy Notes over ssh?

Comment: Maybe you can use [tomboycli](http://code.google.com/p/tomboycli/).

Answer (score 1):

As a quick hack, launch `dbus-launch tomboy`.

Comment: I get `ssh netbook dbus-launch tomboy


[INFO 16:28:04.342] Initializing Mono.Addins
` and nothing happens

Comment: @Richard Holloway: nothing seems to happen, but have you seen in the panel if the icon appears? It appears on my test.

Comment: No, no icon either.